# Why did git checkout print "M" for some unchanged files?

Tags: git

This just happened:

```
$ git branch
* master
...lots of other branches...

$ git checkout -tb feat/bandwidthprelude
M   MANIFEST.in
M   lint.sh
M   setup.py
M   ...some other source files...
Branch 'feat/bandwidthprelude' set up to track local branch 'master'.
Switched to a new branch 'feat/bandwidthprelude'

$ git status
On branch feat/bandwidthprelude
Your branch is up to date with 'master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ...[redacted]...

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

My understanding is that `git checkout`, when switching branches, will print `M` when a file has local modifications. But in this case, according to `git status` (and my memory), **the files did not have local modifications**, though they were files I edited, and committed, recently). I confirmed that the last edits I made were not lost. **What happened?**

If I repeat being on master and `git checkout -tb <branchname>`, the same thing does not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this was a false positive (the modification was real, but not of information Git tracks) triggered by a file metadata change.

Specifically, the unusual thing I did was to accidentally close my editor (TextMate on macOS), which causes it to write some information to open files' metadata and consequently update their modification times. Then a subsequent `git checkout -b` (but *not* a `git checkout` that switches to an existing branch, for some reason) will produce the spurious `M` lines.

The exact same thing happens if I just `touch` a file before `git checkout -b`.

So, just an itty bitty mostly harmless git bug.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of sloppiness on the part of the fast path in checkout, apparently. If you're not actually changing commits it just uses the stat data without refreshing the cached mtimes if appropriate.